# HTML/HP: Emogrifier turns {} into %7B and %7D

Tags: php, html, css

I'm currently setting up an email template which has two parts: The HTML and the CSS. To put everything together and merge the HTML with the CSS I'm using the PHP Emogrifier.

Now I've found out that when I emogrify the two elements that there is a problem with the uft-8 encoding.

All works like Ä, Ü, Ö are correctly displayed but when I put a link like this here into the content, the utf-8 decoding don't works for this element:

Before emogrify:

> `<a href="{password_reset_link}" id="button">Passwort zurücksetzten</a>`

After emogrify:

> ```
> <a href="%7Bpassword_reset_link%7D" id="button" style="color: #69f0ae; text-decoration: none; font-size: 20px; text-align: center; display: block; line-height: 1.7em !important; padding: .3em 1em;
> > border: 2px solid #69f0ae; border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius:
> > 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; width: 40%; margin: auto; cursor:
> > pointer !important;">Passwort zurücksetzten</a>
> ```

So as you can see the href is broken which is set with a placeholder which gets replaced with the correct link after the emogrify process:

```
%7Bpassword_reset_link%7D
```

This is how I emogrify the content:

```
//Apply CSS styles inline for picky email clients.
try {
    $emogrifier = new Emogrifier( $message, $css );
    $message    = $emogrifier->emogrify();
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    $logger = wc_get_logger();
    $logger->error( $e->getMessage(), array( 'source' => 'emogrifier' ) )
}
```

The `$message` and `$css` includes the content and the style. When I do it without the emogrify the link gets successfully replaced. So does anyone has an idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. When you check the Github of the Emogrifier you can see that there was some other bugs with other signs for example a dollar sign `$`. I've fixed it now temporarily with this workaround but this bug needs to get fixed on the Emogrifier itself.

Workaround (hope it helps someone):

```
//Apply CSS styles inline for picky email clients.
try {
    $emogrifier = new Emogrifier( $message, $css );
    $message    = $emogrifier->emogrify();
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    $logger = wc_get_logger();
    $logger->error( $e->getMessage(), array( 'source' => 'emogrifier' ) );
}

$message = str_replace( array( '%7B', '%7D' ), array( '{', '}' ), $message );
```